# I want to remove digits and parenthesis from a data column in dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

can anyone make me understand this piece of code.

```
def remove_digit(data):
    newData = ''.join([i for i in data if not i.isdigit()])
    i = newData.find('(')
    if i>-1: newData = newData[:i]
    return newData.strip()
```

Comment: What if it has multiple '(' your code will just include the second occurrence. Just giving an idea.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you use regex. `[0-9()]` looks for matching characters between `0-9`, `(` and `)`

```
newData = re.sub('[0-9()]', '', data)
```

Answer (score 0):

Give this df:

```
    data
0    a43
1    b((
2  cr3r3
3      d
```

You can remove digits and parenthesis from the column in this way:

```
df['data'] = df['data'].str.replace('\d|\(|\)','')
```

Output:

```
  data
0    a
1    b
2  crr
3    d
```

Comment: Pandas `str.replace()` handles regex. You can simplify your statement to `df['data'].str.replace('\d|\(|\)','')`

Comment: @WStokvis can you please also explain what is ('\d|\(|\)','') ?

Comment: @NimitChhabra It replace digits, ( and ) with empty space ' '

Comment: `\d` is the equivalent of `[0-9]`